# vba- comparação e copia de dados repetidos em coluna

Tags: vba

Ajuda de macro para organização e comparação de repetição de dados em uma coluna na planilha do excel e realizar copia para outro ponto da planilha.

[dados plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU0wE.png)

Comment: Você [já postou essa pergunta antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/561231/70) (e repostou com os mesmos problemas que levaram ao fechamento daquela). Edite sua postagem original melhorando-a (restaure se necessário) que, se vier a atender o objetivo do site, pode ser reaberta pela comunidade via voto. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o campo de comentários desta segunda postagem foi desativado.